# WPF animate button Image

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, wpf-animation

I have a button on which I am adding 2 images. Later on I have to put animation on these images of button.
In below Xaml code I am using button template but after applying the templates button original behavior is lost like there is no border, no change on mouse cursor when hover etc. It is just apear as plan image.

How can I put back the button default behaviour?

```
        <Button Height="89" Margin="0,62,158,0" Name="buttonStart" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="buttonStart_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="133" >
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" >
                <Grid>
                    <Image x:Name="Normal" Source="/TFSCheckinReportGenerator;component/Resource/generate.png" Height="80" Width="80" Opacity="1"></Image>
                    <Image x:Name="Waiting" Source="/TFSCheckinReportGenerator;component/Resource/waiting.png" Height="80" Width="80" Opacity="0"></Image>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>

                    <Storyboard x:Key="ChangeImageToWaiting">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Normal" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Waiting" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>

                    <Storyboard x:Key="Progress" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Waiting" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Duration="00:00:01" AutoReverse="True">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame Value="40"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Waiting" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Duration="00:00:01" AutoReverse="True">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame Value="40"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                    </Storyboard>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Apply [BasedOn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon(v=vs.110).aspx) to a style template instead and inherit the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Template and ControlTemplate use **ContentTemplate** and **DataTemplate** and it will helps to show  button original behavior like  border and change button appearance on mouse hover etc.

[Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx) defines the appearance of the control. [ContentTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplate.aspx) specifies how the content contained in/displayed by a [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx) is to be displayed.

```
 <Button Height="89" Margin="0,62,158,0" Name="buttonStart" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="133" >
        <Button.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Image x:Name="Normal" Source="catalogscreen.png" Height="80" Width="80" Opacity="1"></Image>
                    <Image x:Name="Waiting" Source="catalogscreen.png" Height="80" Width="80" Opacity="0"></Image>
                </Grid>
                <DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="ChangeImageToWaiting">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Normal" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Waiting" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="Progress" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Waiting" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Duration="00:00:01" AutoReverse="True">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame Value="40"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Waiting" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Duration="00:00:01" AutoReverse="True">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame Value="40"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </DataTemplate.Resources>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Button.ContentTemplate>
    </Button>
```